# Several Screen Recording Softwares Tested, All Create Empty Black Frames

Tags: starcraft-2, technical-issues, recording, streaming

I have tested screen recording with Open Broadcaster Software and HyperCam2. Both software have produced full screen videos (HyperCam 2 had better quality, but greater file size using defaults). It seemed to work fine, but once the Starcraft 2 game loads, it would flicker black frames very frequently in its output. I was playing the game on full resolution, and "ultra" settings. Given the specs on my computer, I feel like it should be able to handle the game and recording simultaneously. Any advice or tips on how to record or fix this. Should I try to record in windowed mode? This seems like a workaround, that I can easily test, but I am open to other suggestions as well.

(PC Specs: 2GB DDR5 RADEON R9 270X graphics card, 8 GB High performance DDR3 Ram, and i5 4570 @ 3.2 GHz.  )

Comment: For OBS: What kind of capture did you use? Game Capture works the best and has the best performance of all the capture options.

Answer (score 1):

Running OBS in Game Capture fixed it perfectly, as per GiantTree's comment. I ran it in Monitor mode because I didn't see that setting. Went through some more of the settings and I am VERY impressed with the output I am getting now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how full screen applications/video works.

If you run the game in windowed mode, even windowed mode (full screen), this will not happen.